# How do you add an assembly reference programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4, visual-studio-sdk

I'm using the T4 TextTemplating service from a VSPackage:

```
var t4 = this.GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating;
```

Normally if a template is referencing types in an external assembly you can use the `assembly` directive. However, I don't know the assembly until runtime, so is there anyway of adding assembly references to the T4 engine programmatically?

Comment: Couldn't you just append the assembly directive to the input text, at runtime?

Comment: I'm confused.  T4 templates execute at design time, not runtime.  So if you don't know your assembly reference at design time, how can you expect the T4 to know it?

Comment: In this case, the T4 template is being processed at runtime at the point the ProcessTemplate method is invoked on the TextTemplating service.

Comment: @dbaseman Yes that could be an option, I was wondering if there was a more structured approach, such as 'registering' the assembly with the templating engine or the host in which it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following may be a solution...

Write a custom host, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519.aspx

Before running the engine in that custom host, load the required assemblies using LoadFrom, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx for details.